# Getting Error while create xls-File with XLConnect in R after Linux-Server Update

Tags: java, r, linux, server, xlconnect

I get the following error-massage when I try to open a existing xls-file (that include some macros) and add some data to it in R with the package "XLConnect".

`Error in .jcall("java/lang/Class", "Ljava/lang/Class;", "forName", cl,: RcallMethod: cannot determine object class`

`Warning: Error in h: Error evaluating argument 'Class' in method selection for function 'new': Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>jclassName(class, class.loader = class.loader)new(" jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x55b2c3244c00>, jclass = "java/lang/Throwable")`

I'm working on a LINUX-Server, which I recently updated it. In addition updated R, RStudio and RShiny-Server. Everything worked before the Update. If I run the same Shiny script local on my Win10 PC evrything works fine.I googled a lot and can't find any solution to my problem. Can you guys help me?

Java version *openjdk 11.0.16*

Linux server, R, Shiny-Server and RStudio-Server newest version

Thanks for your help.
Please be kind, I'm new with Linux systems and these things.

**EDIT:**

I'm tried `R CMD javareconf` and get the following output
[consol output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo1R1.png). When I run my Rscript again, I get the same error massage like described above.

Comment: you could use library(openxlsx) to deal with xlsx in R. I think is far superior to XLConnnect.

Comment: You may want to try running `R CMD javareconf` after upgrading various parts of your system.